# Creating Buttons using Xamarin ( VS 2017 ) android app

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to create 2 buttons on my MainPage. I am not sure if i must create them at the xaml file or at the .cs file. What is the right way? I am really new to this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For practice purpose apps(less content) you can write your buttons in .cs file but for the more content/controls app better to xaml.